# To create a package in Oracle DB 10g

Tags: sql, plsql

I have already created procedures (eg. `Insert_stkqnty` and `Insert_receipt`) but suppose I want to put these procedures in a package then what should I do?

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Insert_stkqnty 
    (p_itemid stock_quantity.Item_Id % TYPE, p_date stock_quantity.Date_Received % TYPE, 
     p_supplier stock_quantity.Supplier_Challan % TYPE, p_type stock_quantity.Transaction_Type % TYPE, 
     p_transaction stock_quantity.Transaction_Id % TYPE, p_quantity stock_quantity.Quantity % TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stock_quantity (ID, Item_ID, Date_Received, Supplier_Challan, Transaction_Type, Transaction_ID, Quantity)
    VALUES (seq.nextval, p_itemid, p_date, p_supplier, p_type, p_transaction, p_quantity);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

and the other one

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Insert_receipt 
    (p_receipt receipt.Receipt_Number % TYPE, p_transaction receipt.Transaction_Id % TYPE, p_amount receipt.Amount % TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO receipt (ID, Receipt_Number, Transaction_ID, Amount)
    VALUES (seq.nextval, p_receipt, p_transaction, p_amount);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i have created the prodcedures   `create or replace PROCEDURE Insert_stkqnty( p_itemid stock_quantity.Item_Id%TYPE, p_date stock_quantity.Date_Received%TYPE, p_supplier stock_quantity.Supplier_Challan%TYPE, p_type stock_quantity.Transaction_Type%TYPE, p_transaction stock_quantity.Transaction_Id%TYPE, p_quantity stock_quantity.Quantity%TYPE) IS BEGIN INSERT INTO stock_quantity(ID,Item_ID,Date_Received,Supplier_Challan,Transaction_Type,Transaction_ID,Quantity) VALUES (seq.nextval, p_itemid, p_date,p_supplier,p_type,p_transaction,p_quantity); COMMIT; END;`

Comment: and another one `create or replace PROCEDURE Insert_receipt( p_receipt receipt.Receipt_Number%TYPE, p_transaction receipt.Transaction_Id%TYPE, p_amount receipt.Amount%TYPE) IS BEGIN INSERT INTO receipt( ID, Receipt_Number,Transaction_ID,Amount) VALUES (seq.nextval, p_receipt, p_transaction, p_amount); COMMIT; END;`... I just waant to put these two procedures in a package.... Just need the query

Comment: THEN this.... `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE form AS  -- package body
    PROCEDURE Insert_stkqnty;
    PROCEDURE Insert_receipt;
END form;
/ `

Answer (score 0):

i will give you an example of how it would look like:

function

```
create or replace package body hamming# is   function distance (
    i_first                                       varchar2    ,i_second                                      varchar2   ) return pls_integer   is
    conta                           pls_integer := 0;
    i                             pls_integer := 0;   begin
    for i in 1 .. least(length(i_first), length(i_second)) loop
      if substr(i_first, i, 1) != substr(i_second, i, 1) then
        conta := conta + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return conta;   end distance; end hamming#;
```

procedure

```
create or replace package body binary# is   function to_decimal (
    i_binary                                      varchar2   ) return pls_integer   is
    l_pos_fact                      pls_integer := 1;
    l_pos_val                       number(1);
    l_pos                           pls_integer := length(i_binary);
    l_char                          char(1);
    l_decimal                       pls_integer := 0;   begin
    while l_pos > 0 loop
      l_pos_val := substr(i_binary, l_pos, 1);
      if(not l_pos_val between 0 and 1) then
        raise value_error;
      end if;
      l_decimal  := l_decimal + substr(i_binary, l_pos, 1) * l_pos_fact;
      l_pos      := l_pos - 1;
      l_pos_fact := l_pos_fact * 2;
    end loop;
    return l_decimal;   exception
    when value_error then
      return 0;   end to_decimal; end binary#;
```